# Faster alternative to execute for loop on a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, df that has 10 million rows. I am running the below loop that takes a lot of time to execute. Can there be a faster way to do the same task?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['col_1'][i] not in ['a', 'b']:
        df.at[i,'col_1'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with convert values to `1d array` by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  
                       df['col_1'].values, 
                       np.nan)
```

---

```
#pandas 0.24+
df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  
                       df['col_1'].to_numpy(), 
                       np.nan)
```

Test for `1%` of `a,b` values:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 10 ** 7
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], p=(.05,.05,.9),size=N)})
#print (df)

In [87]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'].values, np.nan)
425 ms ± 2.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [88]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'], np.nan)
442 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [89]: %timeit df.loc[~df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']), 'col_1'] = np.nan
537 ms ± 4.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Test for `50%` of `a,b` values:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 10 ** 7
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], p=(.25,.25,.5),size=N)})
print (df)

In [101]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'].values, np.nan)
532 ms ± 3.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [102]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'], np.nan)
533 ms ± 4.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [103]: %timeit df.loc[~df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']), 'col_1'] = np.nan
602 ms ± 2.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Test for `90%` of `a,b` values:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 10 ** 7
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], p=(.45,.45,.1),size=N)})
print (df)


In [106]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'].values, np.nan)
517 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']),  df['col_1'], np.nan)
520 ms ± 2.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [108]: %timeit df.loc[~df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']), 'col_1'] = np.nan
557 ms ± 2.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.loc[~df['col_1'].isin(['a', 'b']), 'col_1'] = np.nan
```